# Sitecore Security Issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have different areas of our site that we have locked down to specific users. So for example, a user that is a member of the sitecore role 'UK_Editor' can see all other countries content (they only have read access). However, on the UK area they have full access.

The problem is, the user can still go to another Countries content, and the 'publish' button is still available.

Is there a way to restrict this?

Sitecore v: 6.5.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could test out enabling the Publishing.CheckSecurity config setting, should prevent users from being able to publish another sites content with the correct roles applied.

> ```
>        <!--  PUBLISHING SECURITY
>         Check security rights when publishing?
>         When CheckSecurity=true, Read rights are required for all source items. When it is
>         determined that an item should be updated or created in the target database,
>         Write right is required on the source item. If it is determined that the item
>         should be deleted from target database, Delete right is required on the target item.
>         In summary, only the Read, Write and Delete rights are used. All other rights are ignored.
>         Default value: false
>   -->
>         <setting name="Publishing.CheckSecurity" value="true" />
> ```

Comment: Oh, that's a way better (and easier) way to go!

Comment: This is working correctly! thanks so much - but is there built into sitecore for a way to remove the publish button from the menu for these areas they don't have write access to? or would this require quite a bit of work?

Comment: Not that I know of, you'd have to do something custom as @Trayek suggested. You can set security on the Publish item in the core DB but that's by user/role not item security.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to override the `QueryState` of the `PublishItem` class (in `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands`)

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307773/sitecore-hide-button-in-ribbon) for a bit more information.
You'll need to return `CommandState.Hidden` if you want the button to be hidden. You'll need to think of something smart to make sure they can all publish the content in their language, but not in someone elses.

[edit]
It might be possible to do something like `if (Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole('sitecore\englisheditor') && context.Items[0].Language == Sitecore.Data.Managers.GetLanguage('en')) {return base.QueryState(context)}`
Otherwise you can return CommandState.Hidden. I'm not entirely sure about the second part of the if statement though.

Comment: Thanks, thats also kind of what I am trying to do too.

Comment: The only downside is the next update, this will get overwritten :(

Comment: What do you mean? You could change the commands.config file to use your PublishItem command, add that to source control so it'll include in each update.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following blog post, it describes how to security control the UI items associated with publishing in the core database.

http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/why-and-how-hide-publish-site-buttons-in-sitecore/